# No syntax errors, but event listener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom

I can't really seem to find out why this doesn't work:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementsByTagName("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
        alert("hi");
        var bgcolor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        document.body.style.background = bgcolor;
    });
}
```

This script is supposed to load once the document has loaded and change the background color of the website once any button on the site has been pressed.

Comment: can you also share the html?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("button")` returns HTMLCollection not single element. That's why it does not have `.addEventListener` method.

Comment: In your title you say "no syntax errors", but this code would very much result in a run-time error--something like `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...).addEventListener is not a function`.

Comment: @brk What would the HTML have to do with this? It contains some buttons. So what?

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByTagName("button") returns list of element. Which element you want to add event to? If the first one:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function () {
        alert("hi");
        var bgcolor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        document.body.style.background = bgcolor;
    });
};
```

See the [0]? if you want to add to all of them, use for loop or reduce or some other methods. There's plenty to choose from. Your choice.